# Capture All Windows Performance Monitor Counter

Tags: performance, performancecounter, perfmon, performance-monitor

I need to monitor the performance of some servers and thus need to create perfmon counters for that.

At the moment I am having to add the counters manually to create the data collector and this is taking a long time to do as the servers have different customised counters.

Is there an easy way to select all of the counters and collect them instead of selecting and adding one by one?

Thanks
Rikesh

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, you can always export and import your data collector set and then manually adjust it. So you create it once having all the metrics you need and later you can remove the ones you don't need on the other servers.

To import a template you created do this :

- Expand Data Collector Sets
- right click on User Defind
- click new Data Collector Set
- Use the option to work with template
- Browse for your template

[image: Import a Data Collector Set]